# TableviewがStatic CellsかDynamic Prototypesであるか判定したい

Tags: swift, uitableview

ストーリーボード上でtableviewに設定した「Content」プロパティをコードから参照したいのですが、何か方法はあるでしょうか？
「Static Cells」であるか「Dynamic Prototypes」であるかを判定する処理を考えています。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

[image]

Comment: _tableviewに設定した「Content」プロパティをコードから参照したい_ というのは具体的にどういうことでしょうか（Cell上のUILabelなどのことをContentと言っている？）。「Content」というものが何を指しているのかが分かれば、StaticかDynamicかを判定する必要もないのではないかと思います。

Comment: 質問がわかりずらく申し訳ありません。画像を質問文欄に追加致しました。
xcode右ペインのこちらの部分のことです。「Content」という項目名ですが、self.tableView.contentでは参照できず、他のプロパティ名で参照が可能であるかお聞きしたかった次第です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Story Board上で設定できる`content`はプロパティではありません。

Story BoardはUIのクラスをシリアライズしますが、そのときどのようなデータソースを使うのかという違いがあるだけで、両者とも普通の`UITableView`なので、通常の方法では識別できません。

そもそもコード上での両者の実装は、まったく別のものになるはずですので、`content`の値を知る必要があるケースはないように思います。

---

Static Cellsの情報は`staticDataSource`という`UITableViewDataSource`が持っているので、それを利用した判定を書くこと自体はできるのですが、iOS SDKのPrivateな領域なので、実際に使える方法ではありません（リジェクトされる可能性が高い）。

```
if self.valueForKey("staticDataSource") != nil {
    print("static")
} else {
    print("dynamic")
}
```

#### 参考

- [Determine if UITableView has static cells or dynamic prototypes programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130855/determine-if-uitableview-has-static-cells-or-dynamic-prototypes-programmatically)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。リンク先の質問とまさに同じでした。
方法はあるけれどリジェクトされる可能性が高いとのこと、とても勉強になりました。
リンク先でも同じく用途を聞かれていてふふふとなりました。私の場合は、複数あるTableViewControllerの`tableView:tableView:heightForHeaderInSection`等の記述を共通化したかったので、staticかdynamicで判別できれば冗長なソースを短くできるなと考えての質問でした。
頂いたご回答でスッキリ致しました！